# Why are there two separate desktops with KDE?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments, plasma

Running Ubuntu 15.04, and I was fed up with Unity, so I installed kubuntu-desktop. Works fine, switch to it at login.

There's a weird behavior that I can't find explained elsewhere however - I appear to have two desktops on top of one another somehow. I don't know if this is intended behavior, or how to change it.

If I am on a virtual desktop with no windows, Alt-Tab switches from the desktop with the menu icon in the corner and right click to add widgets to one that acts a normal desktop with no widgets - right click to add folder. Changing the wallpaper of one does not change the other, nor do icons show up on both (asking Steam to make a desktop icon put it on the non widget one, which also showed up when I logged out and switched back to Unity.) Changing between virtual desktops does not switch this behavior - whatever desktop type it's on stays between virtual desktops, I just seem to only be able to swap between them if Alt-Tab has no other windows to switch to.

Does anyone know what's going on? Is my gnome desktop underneath KDE or something, and if so can I make it go away?

---

Pressing Alt-Tab with no open windows swaps between these two desktops

[image: Desktop with widgets]

[image: Desktop with folders]

Comment: Can you edit the post to add pictures? The problem is not clear enough.